# Can two classes inherit from each other at the same time?

Tags: c++, class

I don't have any coding issues today, but i need some help in explaining a concept im struggling to find answers to. The question is:

Can you have class X inheriting from class Y and 
class Y inheriting from class X at the same time? Explain using code.

Comment: Inheritance is an "is a" relationship. You can have "B is an A", or "A is a B", but how would "A is a B is an A is a B is an A..." work?

Comment: Why would you want that? Or is it the question just theoretical?

Comment: Nope.  Functionally,the representation of a derived classes includes a representation of each of each base class.  If two classes inherit mutually from each other, then the representation of an X would contain a representation of a Y which contains a representation of an X, and the "contain a representation of" relationship would be infinitely recursive.    It's the same reason that a `struct` type cannot, directly or indirectly, contain a complete instance of itself - the relationship is infinitely recursive.

Comment: @churill it was part of a class discussion, i was just interested in the answer

Answer (score 5):

It was already said in a comment: (public) inheritance models a "is a" relationship.

Forget about C++ for a moment and consider the abstract concept of inheritance and what it models. If `A` inherits from `B` then any instance of `A` is a `B`. Hence the set of all instances of `A` is a subset of all instances of `B`. If all instances of `A` are instances of `B` and all instances of `B` are instances of `A`, then no inheritance is needed to model the relation between `A` and `B`, because they are the exact same type.

Now C++ again. This:

```
 struct A : B {};
 struct B : A {};
```

Is not possible for two reasons. First, to make `A` inherit from `B` the definition of `B` must be known, and to make `B` inherit from `A` the definition of `A` must be known. Second, each instance of `A` contains a subobject of type `B` and each `B` contains a subobject of type `A` and every `A` .... ad infinitum. It is not possible.